# Hive - fetch only the latest partition of one or more hive tables

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-partitions

I have three partitioned tables (Yearly Partitions) in Hive and all the tables have multiple partitions. I am joining all these three tables as part of my requirement. Now I want to run this sql only for the latest partition and not for the ones created before.

I tried to use max(partition) in where clause but it seems it is not supported

I did something like below (not the exact code. Just a code concept)

```
select
a.*,
b.*,
c.*
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
left join table3 c on a.ID = c.ID
where
a.year = max(a.year) and
b.year = max(b.year) and
c.year = max(c.year)
```

I got this error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 108:23 Not yet supported
>   place for UDAF 'max'

I can use multiple where clauses with a subquery containing "select max(year) from table" for all the table but that's not seem to be a feasible one. Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

**UPDATE** 
I tried the where clause with conditions below but it seems only one suq-query is supported in the where clause. Not sure how to resolve this. Appreciating any inputs on this

```
where
a.year in (select max(year) from table1) and
b.year in (select max(year) from table2) and
c.year in (select max(year) from table3
```

Comment: why do you think it is not feasible? i'm using that one to get maxes

Comment: Ok. For easy reference I mentioned as the table has only year as the partition but in actual case it has more partition columns and I have more tables to join. So I don't think it's feasible.

Comment: does it matter how many partition types the table has? it's all about modifying "where" clause. moreover, your aggregate function (i.e. max) is applied on partition column, not a usual one, so even the speed is not a concern here

Comment: @mangusta Thanks for your inputs . I will try the same and post it here if there is any performance discrepancy.

Comment: @mangusta I am not able to introduce more than one subqueries in the where clause. Updated the question to contain more details. Any ideas ?

Comment: how about using the one in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Modified version:

```
    select
    <columns>
    from  
    (  
     select 
     <columns> 
     from 
     table1 a 
     where a.year in (select max(year) from table1) 
    ) a1
    left join 
    (
     select 
     <columns> 
     from 
     table2 b 
     where b.year in (select max(year) from table2) 
    ) b1 on a1.ID = b1.ID
    left join 
    (
     select 
     <columns> 
     from 
     table3 c 
     where c.year in (select max(year) from table3) 
    ) c1 on a1.ID = c1.ID
;
```